# Object representation in Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, representation

Assume I have the following class, 'MyClass'.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Myclass()'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Meh'

instances = [MyClass() for i in range(5)]
```

Some instances are created and stored in the `instances` variable. Now, we check its content.

```py
>>> instances
[Myclass(), Myclass(), Myclass(), Myclass(), Myclass()]
```

To represent the object python calls the `__repr__` method. However, when the same `instances` variable is passed to a `pandas.DataFrame`, the representation of the object changes and the `__str__` method seemed to be called.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=instances)
```

```py
>>> df
     0
0  Meh
1  Meh
2  Meh
3  Meh
4  Meh
```

Why has the object's representation changed? Can I determine which representation is used in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is indeed stored as object. It seems pandas just calls the `__str__` method (implicitly) when it displays the dataframe.

You can verify that by calling:

```
df[0].map(type)
```

It calls `type` for each element in the column and returns:

```
Out[572]: 
0    <class '__main__.MyClass'>
1    <class '__main__.MyClass'>
2    <class '__main__.MyClass'>
3    <class '__main__.MyClass'>
4    <class '__main__.MyClass'>
Name: 0, dtype: object

# likewise you get the the
# representation string of the objects
# with:
df[0].map(repr)
Out[578]: 
0    Myclass()
1    Myclass()
2    Myclass()
3    Myclass()
4    Myclass()
Name: my_instances, dtype: object
```

Btw, if you want to create a dataframe with a column that contains the data explicitly, rather use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_instances': instances})
```

This way, you assign a column name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was indeed suspecting a different internal call. However, what makes it strange is that numpy for instance uses the repr internally, so you would expect pandas to do the same. Any idea how I can change the object's representation?

Comment: I guess that is, because `pandas` is also used in `jupyter` notebooks whose output is meant to look nice, while `repr` is usually used for debug output or in tools (e.g. if the class of an object is relevant). But how do you want to change the representation? you already used the two relevant methods in your class, do you mean something else?